# Django - Error socialregistration.middleware

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

Just now I clone my remote repo from my server to my computer with mercurial.

I changed settings.py for set sqlite3 as database engine and I tried to run Django built-in webserver:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3, using settings 'myproj.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 283, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware socialregistration.middleware: "No module named facebook"
[26/May/2011 22:22:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 959
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 283, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware socialregistration.middleware: "No module named facebook"
```

All is ok on my server. Why this in localhost?

**-- UDPATE**

Installed pyfacebook and fixed it. Now I get this error visiting /

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'myapp',
 'avatar',
 'socialregistration']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'socialregistration.middleware.FacebookMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  89.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/Users/fredcollins/Desktop/myproj/socialregistration/middleware.py" in process_request
  23.         fb_user = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(request.COOKIES,

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_user_from_cookie'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to install [`facebook`](https://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/) on your server.

Comment: and then remember to do a `syncdb`

Comment: On my server all is ok. The problem is locally.

Comment: All it works. Solution: https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration/issues/37

Comment: @Ignacio, while I'm sure your answer is correct, I don't understand *why* `pyfacebook` is needed. It isn't mentioned in the docs for django-socialregistration anywhere. And the link describes it as a "client library for the Facebook API" - isn't that what *django-socialregistration* is for? :)

Comment: @John: No, because it's dumb to duplicate code that already exists in a usable form.

Comment: So, does the [python-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk) in the *django-socialregistration* docs, perform the same function as the [pyfacebook](https://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/) that you linked in your Answer? Are they interchangeable in terms of getting *django-socialregistration* working, or is one preferable?

Comment: @John: That I don't know specifically. It is possible that they provide the same API.